# Keeps saying I must declare guest_id, can anyone provide insight to this issue?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

```sql
    create or replace procedure new_guest(
p_guest_id in guest_id%type,
p_guet_first_name in guest_first_name%type,
p_guest_last_name in guest_last_name%type, 
p_DOB in DOB%type, 
p_drivers_license_state in drivers_license_state%type, 
p_drivers_license_no in drivers_license_no%type, 
p_other_details in other_details%type
)
is
begin 
insert into GUEST ("guest_id", "guest_first_name", "guest_last_name", "DOB", "drivers_license_state", 
"drivers_license_no", "other_details")
values (p_guest_id, p_guest_first_name, p_guest_last_name, p_DOB, p_drivers_license_state, 
p_drivers_license_no, p_other_details); 
commit; 
end; 
/
```

Comment: Column names do not get double-quoted. MySQL uses backticks, all other languages use nothing unless the column name contains a space, in which case they have to be surrounded with `[]`. Also, your parameter declarations are all wrong - `in` does not belong there. You should find a good SQL tutorial or book to learn the basics; it will make future tasks much easier to accomplish.

Comment: This looks like Oracle. Please tag with the RDBMS (Oracle) and the version if possible